# How can we insert new records in magento2 db using sql queries

Tags: magento2, database, data-migration, bulk-products-update

Let us know the exact way to import bulk data to DB using queries.

Answer (score 2):

Write custom MYSQL query without using Model

Here is example how to write custom mysql query in Magento2.

Suppose we have table `employee` with fields `emp_id`, `emp_name`, `emp_code` and `emp_salary`.

Now use following code to run custom queries in magento2 without using model.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Instance of object manager
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();
$tableName = $resource->getTableName('employee'); //gives table name with prefix

//Select Data from table
$sql = "Select * FROM " . $tableName;
$result = $connection->fetchAll($sql); // gives associated array, table fields as key in array.

//Delete Data from table
$sql = "Delete FROM " . $tableName." Where emp_id = 10";
$connection->query($sql);

//Insert Data into table
$sql = "Insert Into " . $tableName . " (emp_id, emp_name, emp_code, emp_salary) Values ('','XYZ','ABD20','50000')";
$connection->query($sql);

//Update Data into table
$sql = "Update " . $tableName . "Set emp_salary = 20000 where emp_id = 12";
$connection->query($sql);
```

For more reference [Click here](http://www.blogtreat.com/magento-2-run-custom-sql-query-without-using-model/)